# Switch between tabs in Sublime Text Vintage Mode

Tags: vim, vi, sublimetext

I know we can achieve this in VIM using nerdtree and gT and gt commands. But is there any way to achieve similar kind of behaviour in Sublime Text Vintage Mode?

Comment: Does splat-shift-] work?

Comment: no, not working. But thanks Andy.

Comment: cmd-shift-] and cmd-shift- [ works for me ;) thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think Vintage mode has these bound to `gt`, `gT` or anything but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> do exactly the same thing as `gt` and `gT`, whether you are in Vintage mode (INSERT or NORMAL) or not.

You know, there is a very easy way to find the shortcuts used by an application: just look at the menu bar. That's what I did for you and it took less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your help romainl. I just came to know how idiot I am. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: lol, don't take him so seriously. I am looking at the menu bar on Sublime right now and those shortcuts are definitely not immediately apparent. In fact, I still haven't found them :)

Comment: lol, don't take him so seriously. He is looking at the menu bar on Sublime right now and those shortcuts are definitely immediately apparent. In fact, [he is blind](http://i.imgur.com/O8kuGhK.png). Or high. Or…

Comment: Hardly clear for a newcomer to Sublime. In fact "Next file in stack" has no indication that you are really switching between "Tabs." The menu labels are certainly different than most applications and many of the concepts are used under new Sublime-specific names.

Comment: I think they changed the label since my answer, otherwise I would have indicated the weird name as a courtesy to the asker and probably ranted a bit on the importance of using "standard" labels and finding the right level of abstraction. Anyway, I've never used ST for more than 20 minutes (in fact, I had to download it to take that screenshot) and it was *very* quick and easy, even with the weird label, to find the answer. Discoverability is one of the main bebefits of GUI tools, leveraging it is not even a matter of curiosity at that point.

Answer (score 32):

Or (for posterity), you can just paste this in your keymap file:

```
{ "keys": ["g", "t"], "command": "next_view",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": true },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["g", "T"], "command": "prev_view",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": true },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I like this solution but with "next_view_in_stack" and "prev_view_in_stack" to have it cycle through the current column focus group.

Comment: Hi Veered, for the life of me, I can't seem to find the API fo all these commands like "next_view". Do you have the link handy?

Comment: This answer is 6+ years old, perhaps `next_view`/`prev_view` isn't supported anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Vintageous on ST3 will give you much more than the default Vintage package provides.