# Vintage Sublime Text go to tab N

Tags: vim, sublimetext

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488650/347284) covered how to switch between tabs with `gt` and `gT` like in Vim. Would there be a way to add the ability to type `3gt` to go to tab 3? All [the documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands) mentions is a `focusView` command which accepts an argument, but it seems related to groups (?), and the following first try doesn't work:

```
{
    "keys": ["z", "t"], "command": "focusView", "args": {"view": 1}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": true },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are hitting the limit where vim emulators start to show their limitations. If you want Vim, use Vim.

Comment: Vim is limited in some ways compared to Sublime Text to me, especially in the way it handles long lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it matters, but those are ST1 docs. The command is probably `focus_view` (though I haven't checked it). If you are using ST3, I'd recommend trying [Vintageous](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous). It appears to be much more complete than the built in vintage mode. For example, `3gt` does move you to the third tab with this plugin.

Comment: Thanks, it works! The last time I've tried Vintageous I had issues with it so I haven't kept using it, but I sure should give it a new try.